# WebRTC how to differentiate the video quality sent to peers

Tags: javascript, streaming, video-streaming, p2p, webrtc

I need a bit of help with this new amazing technology called webRTC.

Let's consider this scenario for a WebRTC mesh network with three peers. The Peer A has an HD stream from its cam and it is sharing with the other 2 peers B and C. B and C are not sending any data. The connection between A and B is rather good and the peer B can enjoy the video at full HD. While the connection between A and C is slower than A and B and it does not support an HD stream, thus B is not having a smooth stream. Nevertheless B would smoothly support a lower quality video, for instance 640x480.

I would like to provide a smooth video experience to both clients. I could reduce the quality video of the source calling getUserMedia with a lower quality but this is not a good solution because it would reduce the quality of the video even for the peers that support HD (B) .

What I would like to have is that the source peer ( A ) gets a stream at its maximum quality, in this case HD. Then the quality of the video to send to a peer is chosen according to the connection characteristic between the source and that peer. In our previous example :

```
                   HD (1280x720)
              /------------------->     B 
     A       /
  stream HD /
 (1280x720) \  
             \    HD (640x480)
              \------------------->     C
```

How can I achieve this result? Can I modify the SDP descriptor to set the video resolution just for that session?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, WebRTC can automatically adjust video quality based on network bandwidth.

Try to send HD video to both users B and C, WebRTC engine should automatically set max possible quality

Comment: How is max possible quality determined? Does A have to create a downsized stream specially for C to consume? Would that double the computational requirements?